# Working with cursors (NOT WORKING)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been following tutorial on [Working With Cursors](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html) here. I wondered , where is the appropriate file code location modules for this cursor tutorial. Let's say I want to reuse this tutorial module on [People Pieces](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#a-directory-of-people-working-with-pieces) . I have this code on **people/index.js**.

```js
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    permissionsFields : true,
    name: 'person',
    label: 'Person',
    pluralLabel: 'People',
    addFields : [
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            label: 'First Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'lastName',
            label: 'Last Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: 'title',
            label: 'Full Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            contextual: true
        },
        {
            name: 'slug',
            label: 'Slug',
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            contextual: true
        },
        {
            name: 'body',
            label: 'Biography',
            type: 'area',
            options: {
                widgets: {
                    'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                        toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
                    },
                    'apostrophe-images': {}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'phone',
            label: 'Phone',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'thumbnail',
            label: 'Thumbnail',
            type: 'singleton',
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
            options: {
                limit: 1,
                minSize: [200, 200],
                aspectRatio: [1, 1]
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'reputation',
            label: 'Reputation',
            type: 'integer'
        }
    ],
    arrangeFields: [{
            name: 'contact',
            label: 'Contact',
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone']
        },
        {
            name: 'admin',
            label: 'Administrative',
            fields: ['slug', 'published', 'tags']
        },
        {
            name: 'content',
            label: 'Biographical',
            fields: ['thumbnail', 'body']
        }
    ],
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
            // Override title and MUST SET CONTEXTUAL to able to save. Let the 
            // backend self.beforeSave method do this thing.
            // You know why I don't set piece.slug ?
            // Because once you already set title , apostrophe made it for you :)
            // BUT must put contextual : true on slug. If not, it will prompt you :*
            piece.title = piece.firstName + ' ' + piece.lastName;
            return callback();
        }

        return self.apos.docs.getManager('person').find(req, {
                reputation: {
                    $gte: 30
                }
            }).sort({
                updatedAt: -1
            })
            .toArray(function (err, people) {
                console.log(people);
            });
    }
};
```

It Outputs the result on console like this :

`.find() is undefined`

But then , i tried to use on browser side where self.pushAsset is involve, still does not console.log anything ! I know I should follow that tutorial using those schema. But let's brainstorming the code for a while for better understanding. How about if I reuse the code for the schema that I did on People Pieces ? Or is there any specific requirement or method to use for apos.getManager(piecesName) ? Oh btw, I did experimenting on people-widget/index.js too, but it did not workout with same error output. If this tutorial that I cannot follow , I will never did understand to use that code. I love ApostropheCMS <3

Comment: When do you want it to happen? And what do you want to do with the data once you have it? With that information I can tell you where you should add the code. It doesn't work right now because it's not inside any method of the module, it's right in the constructor of the module, running too soon at website startup.

We definitely need to improve that section of the documentation with a good sample project showing where cursors might be used.

Comment: I agree that docs should be improved on that section with a good sample project . About "When do I want it to happen" is just an experimenting code with console.log of array of people. I simply want to find a reputation numbers where approx total of 30 . A simple output would be enough . Although , the error handler also needed to be improve on that part . It only shows 'apos is not defined' . And I tried so many times using different method . Nothing works. Well , I tried on "People" modules where I followed your tutorials. Looking for future improvements ! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for it. I also solve the `req not defined` on my terminal console.

So I did this in **`app.js`** for cursor. Finally , it did output this stuff .

```js
      'people-pages' : {
        extend : 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
        construct: function (self, options) {
          return self.apos.docs.getManager('person').find({
            reputation: {
              $gte: 30
            }
          }).toArray(function (err, people) {
            console.log("List of peoples \n",people);
          });
        }
      },
```